# i want to write a script to check if my website is still running over ftp in IIS 5 after rebooting the server

Tags: ftp, iis-5

I have a website hosted in IIS 5. This website is hosted with FTP. I want to write a **script** to check if my website is still running when i am rebooting my server. Where can i get some *code sample* for help for such a legacy server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a console script, you could write a `curl` command or a powershell command to hit some URL/asset in your site

for example: `curl http://somewhere/header.jpg` will error if it can't reach that (meaning the web host is down).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this.